# Получение ленты новостей для пользователя

Tags: vkontakte-api

Есть список пользователей, которые подписаны на группу. Задача узнать кто из пользователей, которые состоят в группе скрыл ее в новостной ленте. Я смотрел в сторону метода newsfeed, но похоже не понимаю, как его использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак, это их личная настройка.